# Few perfume questions

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, conversation

Imagine a following situation.

> Mike and Natalie share same preferences in perfume. They both like
>   sweet, clean and soft aroma/scent.
>
> Two other people - Kate and Jane - are talking about Mike. And Kate
>   notes that she likes an aroma of perfume that Mike uses. Jane are
>   asking her friend what perfume Mike wears and Kate have decided
>   to describe it in following way:
>
> **He wears same ones as Natalie does.**

**Main Q.** Is it correct way to say it? How would you point on same preferences of both in given conversation?

**Additional Q1** Is it okay to say "wearing perfume"? I see examples with this collocation in the Internet, but still better to ask and be perfectly sure.

**Additional Q2** What the difference between words "aroma" and "scent" in terms of perfume? In my native language we use the word "aroma" mostly with very few occasions of using "scent", but from what I see (*and may be totally wrong!*) the word "scent" is acceptable in English too.

**Thanks.**

Comment: In the US (and I suspect in many other English-speaking countries as well), men wear _cologne_, and women wear _perfume_. They may share the same preferences, but it's very unlikely Mike would wear the same perfume as Natalie.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I did not know that. You see, in my country word "cologne" has a negative sense. Back in USSR people were forced to use national colognes only, with no foreign alternatives (Iron Curtain, what I can say?). These colognes were scenting awful, but since we have no other choice we wear then. When USSR was crashed, tons of foreign man perfumes and toilet waters (dior, channel, hugo, etc.) were imported, and from 90s we started to use word "cologne" mostly to describe awful soviet perfumes from the past and in some comic reliefs. But this a offtop, thank you for clever point!

Comment: And for "...but it's very unlikely Mike would wear the same perfume as Natalie..", well, unisex maybe? =) But I see your point, yes my terminology is wrong.

Comment: @J.R. I was going to say, that in the UK men's perfume is most often described as "after-shave". But I now realise that, as with so many things, I am about 30 years behind the times. In my youth, a guy could have had a beard three feet long, but it would still have been called "after-shave". But just looking at some advertisements I see the use of euphemisms such as "Eau de toilette" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He wears the same ones as Natalie does.

is correct, since it is in the plural, it implies they both wear several different perfumes which are the same. I you wanted to say the perfumes are similar but not exactly the same

> He wears perfumes *similiar* to Natalie's, they both like sweet, clean and soft aroma/scent**s**.

Yes, people **wear** perfume.

Usually the smell of perfume is referred to as a **scent**, **aroma** is often used for things like food or coffee which is consumed.

Comment: ... *the* same ones (as) Natalie does

Comment: "He wears perfumes similiar to Natalie": Shouldn't this be "He wears perfumes similiar to Natalie's"?